# How do I make my headset button resume podcast player instead of music player?

Tags: applications, bluetooth, media-player, headset-controls

I am using Samsung Galaxy A10e on Android 11. I have [AIMP](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.aimp.player) music player and [Free Offline Podcast Player FM](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=fm.player) installed. I am also using the Groove "onn. Wireless Neckband" headset.

I have just installed [Bluetooth connect & Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cp2.start.and.play.music.player), but it does not do this. I even force-stopped the music player in the apps menu, but no change.

How do I make my headset button resume the podcast player instead of the music player?